# Vue chart only loading data after resizing the window

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, apexcharts

I am using an apexchart on my code to display a chart with some data, however my data is not shown when the page loads, it only shows if I zoom in/zoom out or resize the window which I find kinda weird.
I've found a similar issue on the apexcharts github but it has been open since 2019 and is not really active so I'm asking here maybe someone had the same issue and found some way to fix it.

---

Here's my apexchart:

```
<v-col cols="12">
 <apexchart
  type="line"
  height="350"
  :options="chartOptions"
  :series="series"
 ></apexchart>
</v-col>
```

Here's my chartOptions:

```
chartOptions: {
    chart: {
      height: 350,
      type: "line",
      zoom: {
        enabled: false,
      },
      toolbar: {
        show: false,
      },
    },
    legend: {
      labels: {
        colors: "#FFFFFF",
      },
    },
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: false,
    },
    stroke: {
      curve: "straight",
    },
    title: {
      align: "left",
    },
    grid: {
      row: {
        colors: ["#f3f3f3", "transparent"], // takes an array which will be repeated on columns
        opacity: 0.5,
      },
    },
    xaxis: {
      type: "datetime",
      categories: [],
      labels: {
        datetimeUTC: false,
        style: {
          colors: "#FFFFFF",
        },
      },
    },
    yaxis: [
      {
        title: {
          text: "Energie",
          style: {
            color: "#FFFFFF",
          },
        },
        labels: {
          style: {
            colors: "#FFFFFF",
          },
        },
        decimalsInFloat: 1,
      },
      {
        opposite: true,
        title: {
          text: "Puissance",
          style: {
            color: "#FFFFFF",
          },
        },
        labels: {
          style: {
            colors: "#FFFFFF",
          },
        },
        decimalsInFloat: 1,
      },
    ],
    tooltip: {
      enabled: false,
    },
    colors: ["#8AB4F7", "#8DCD7F"],
  },
```

Comment: I don't know how or when you define series but maybe you can try using apexcharts updateSeries method https://apexcharts.com/docs/methods/#updateSeries

Comment: @PatrykLaszuk updating tthe series actually removed my data, it displays me an empty chart (even when resizing the window)

Answer (score 0):

Set a ref to your chart `<apexchart ref="chart_ref"/>` and call following line:

```
this.$refs.chart_ref.refresh()
```

You can also wrap this line in nextTick or setTimeout (0) if still bugging.